# Why is null < 1 true in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, null

Why do `null < 1` and several of the following comparisons evaluate to `true` in JavaScript?

```js
document.write("null == 1 is " + (null == 1) + "<br />");
document.write("null == 0 is " + (null == 0) + "<br />");
document.write("<hr />");
document.write("null < 1 is " + (null < 1) + " ???<br />");
document.write("null >= 1 is " + (null >= 1) + "<br />");
document.write("<hr />");
document.write("null < 0 is " + (null < 0) + "<br />");
document.write("null >= 0 is " + (null >= 0) + " ???<br />");
document.write("<hr />");
document.write("null > 1 is " + (null > 1) + "<br />");
document.write("null <= 1 is " + (null <= 1) + " ???<br />");
document.write("<hr />");
document.write("null > 0 is " + (null > 0) + "<br />");
document.write("null <= 0 is " + (null <= 0) + " ???<br />");
```

Comment: If you force null to be interpreted in a numeric context then it is
 treated like 0

Comment: Wow, thanks. Sorry, I did not find that other question via Google or the question search on this site.

Comment: No worries same as false < 1 // true